# Calling WebApi from Console Application is Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi that is running on Azure and fully tested via Postman

[image]

This API takes 2 headers

```
Content-Type: application/json
AppToken: {{AppToken}}
```

I want to call this API from a console application and I thought it is a pretty straight forward process. Here is my Main program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
   {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("BASE_ADDRESS/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AppToken", "MY_APP_TOKEN_VALUE");


        // Call API to create the registration
        CreateRegistration(client).Wait();
    }
public static async Task CreateRegistration(HttpClient client)
        {
            using (client)
            {
                try
                {
                    Registration reg1 = new Registration { email = "test@ssdafsds.com", clientId = 2342342, registrationId = 23423, ProgramId = 13 };
                    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/register", reg1);

                    responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    // Handle success
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle failure
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting an internal server error as the "Reason Phrase" with status code 500. I am not sure why I am getting this error. I should be getting 201 Created like postman

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: 500 is a generic response from the server indicating something happened internally it didn't expect. This maybe your fault, or theirs, a product of bad design, or any number of things. If postman works, i would suggest using fiddler and comparing the 2 requests and debugging the issue with all the information at hand.

Comment: Postman can generate code for your lanfuage and try... if it works, just compare codes

Comment: @Clystian I did not think of that. This worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: did you try to read responseMessage content before to EnsureSuccessStatusCode or what exception message says?

Comment: It gave me a general exception "Internal server error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake by passing a program id that I don't actually have in my database which failed the FK_Reference and caused this issue. Thank you all for your help.